# How can I annotate nested objects with interfaces for configuration check?

Tags: javascript, typescript, interface

Was looking into [typescript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/) to have type check on a configuration file like the following:

```
const _config = {
    local: {
        host: 'localhost',
        port: 1234
    },
    dev: {
        host: 'https://dev.myapp.com',
        port: 80
    },
    prod: {
        host: 'https://prod.myapp.com',
        port: 80
    },
}

export const config = _config[process.env.NODE_ENV || 'dev'];
```

I would like to annotate the nested objects to conform to an interface, basically to check that there are no missing configuration properties at compile time (instead of runtime):

```
interface IConfig {
    host: string;
    port: number;
}

const _config = {
    local: { // <-- I would like to annotate this object with type IConfig
        host: 'localhost',
        port: 1234
    },
    dev: { // <-- I would like to annotate this object with type IConfig
        host: 'https://dev.myapp.com',
        port: 80
    },
    prod: { // <-- I would like to annotate this object with type IConfig
        host: 'https://prod.myapp.com',
        port: 80
    },
}

export const config = _config[process.env.NODE_ENV || 'dev'];
```

Is this possible? Or any alternative way to achieve the same thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an index signature and provide an interface for the entire configuration.

```
interface Environment {
    host: string;
    port: number;
}

interface Config {
    [name: string]: Environment;
}

const _config: Config = {
    local: {
        host: 'localhost',
        port: 1234
    },
    dev: {
        host: 'https://dev.myapp.com',
        port: 80
    },
    prod: {
        host: 'https://prod.myapp.com',
        port: 80
    },
}

export const config = _config[process.env.NODE_ENV || 'dev'];
```

Comment: It seems the most elegant solution among the ones provided (for now)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to use an interface for the config object itself? So you could do something like

```
interface IConfigProperty {
  host: string
  port: number
}

interface IConfig {
  local: IConfigProperty
  dev: IConfigProperty
  prod: IConfigProperty
}

const _config: IConfig = {
    local: { 
        host: 'localhost',
        port: 1234
    },
    dev: {
        host: 'https://dev.myapp.com',
        port: 80
    },
    prod: { 
        host: 'https://prod.myapp.com',
        port: 80
    },
}

export const config = _config[process.env.NODE_ENV || 'dev'];
```

Comment: Thanks! Also see my other answer

Answer (score 1):

For further type-safety, I would recommend this instead. We can make use of [type aliases](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#string-literal-types) to provided typings for `host`.

```
type Host = 'localhost' | 'https://dev.myapp.com' | 'https://prod.myapp.com';

interface Config {
  [name: string]: IConfig;
}

interface IConfig {
    host: Host;
    port: number;
}

const _config: Config = {
    local: { 
        host: 'localhost',
        port: 1234
    },
    dev: {
        host: 'https://dev.myapp.com',
        port: 80
    },
    prod: { 
        host: 'https://prod.myapp.com',
        port: 80
    },
};
```

If you wish, you can even declare type aliases for the name of your configs(`local`, `dev`, `prod`)

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to annotate the parent object:

```
interface IConfig {
    host: string;
    port: number;
}

const _config: { local: IConfig, dev: IConfig, prod: IConfig } = {
    local:
        host: 'localhost',
        port: 1234
    },
    dev:
        host: 'https://dev.myapp.com',
        port: 80
    },
    prod:
        host: 'https://prod.myapp.com',
        port: 80
    },
}

export const config: IConfig = _config[process.env.NODE_ENV || 'dev'];
```